# Vagrant VM stuck in 'stopping' state

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant

I cannot shutdown a VirtualBox VM on a Linux host, launched by Vagrant:

```
$ vagrant halt -f my-vm
$ vagrant status
Current machine states:

my-vm                stopping (virtualbox)

The VM is stopping.
```

This seems to be stuck. I try to poweroff with VBox commands, but that also fails:

```
$ VBoxManage list vms
"my-vm-id_my-vm_1516891695543_61345" {cb29c90c-30c7-4798-9bd7-9d8ee32e1530}

$ VBoxManage controlvm cb29c90c-30c7-4798-9bd7-9d8ee32e1530 poweroff
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine is being powered down
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "PowerDown(progress.asOutParam())" at line 231 of file VBoxManageControlVM.cpp
```

What is the best way to halt now?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Only way I could do it is by killing the process:

```
ps aux | grep VBox
```

Then, select the appropiate vm process pid and:

```
kill $pid
```